# Does the kernel have AUFS support

Tags: kernel

I am trying to use [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback) with ElemntaryOS, but the resulting backup will not boot for want of AUFS support.  Is the kernel modified from the base Ubuntu kernel?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to solve it:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "overlay\naufs" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules'

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install `aufs-tools`. Type in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt install aufs-tools
```

Comment: Thanks -- good suggestion!.  I did need to install `aufs-tools`.  Unfortunately, doing so didn't fix the problem.  After adding `aufs tools`, I created a new `systemback` backup, but got the same error.  Not sure what the issue is because the kernel appears to have `aufs` support.